# Android timing in OpenGL ES thread is not monotonic

Tags: android, timer, opengl-es-2.0

I'm measuring time interval for looped animations/particles/etc in my Android app. App is a live wallpaper so it doesn't prevent system from scaling clock down for power saving.
Because of this all methods to measure time intervals between last frames doesn't measure monotonic time - I experience animations inconsistently slowing down and speeding up.

I've used all possible methods to retrieve system time - all of them are not monotonic (even `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` and `System.nanoTime()` which are *guaranteed* to be monotonic but nope they are not).

If I hold a finger on screen to prevent power saving all animations are smooth.
This issue is very noticeable on Nexus10, slightly noticeable on Nexus7 1st gen and on Nexus4 it is not present at all.

Here is code excerpt to measure time:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    // calculate timers for animations based on difference between lastFrameTime and SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    ...
    // save last timestamp for this frame
    lastFrameTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm: Are you completely certain that the animation speed is slowing down? It's not just a reduced frame rate that makes the animation look jerky? I figure you calculate the time since the last frame, and multiply it with the speed of your particles to calculate the position increment? Are you logging the raw time values, and you see the time moving backwards?

Comment: I'm sure this is not frameskip. Animation doesn't get jerky, I just get random 'slo-mo' effect. There's not that much to draw - I get steady 50-60 fps, but all movement of objects gradually slows down and gets back to normal speed at inconsistent time intervals.

Comment: Not sure what's going on then. Note that strictly speaking, "monotonic" only means that the clock value never goes backwards. It doesn't mean that it runs at a constant speed. So the guarantee would not be violated if it slows down and speeds up. Still, with the way the functions are named and specified, one would expect them to give useful time measurements.

Comment: Sorry, comment limits... Looking at the outline of your code, I would structure it a little differently. I would call `elapsedRealtime()` at the **start** of `onDrawFrame()` and assign it to a variable which I'll call `currentFrameTime`. Then use `currentFrameTime - lastFrameTime` as the delta time to update your animations. Then, at the end of `onDrawFrame()`, assign `lastFrameTime = currentFrameTime`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi please answer question instead of putting comment so I'll accept your answer. Your solution works like a charm.

Comment: Will do. It was just a wild guess (well, a somewhat educated guess), so I wasn't confident enough to post it as an answer.

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` is ***not*** guaranteed to be monotonic. Its only guarantee is that it use the highest-resolution timer available on a system. If that means using a CPU instruction like `RDTSC`, which will give non-monotonic results if a thread changes CPU/cores, then that is perfectly acceptable by the requirements given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding a little on what I think you're doing based on the outline of your code, your `onDrawFrame()` method in pseudo code looks like this:

```
deltaTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastFrameTrime
// point 1, see text below
update animation based on deltaTime
draw frame
// point 2, see text below
lastFrameTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
```

The problem with this sequence is that you lose the time between point 1 and point 2 from your total animation time. You need to make sure that the total sum of all your `deltaTime` values, which are the times applied to your animation, covers the entire wall clock time of the amimation. With the logic you use, this is not the case. You only add up the times between the **end** of one call to the **start** of the next call. You do not account for the time needed to execute the method, which can be significant.

This can be fixed with a slight change in the sequence:

```
currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
deltaTime = currentTime - lastFrameTime
lastFrameTime = currentTime
update animation based on deltaTime
draw frame
```

The key point is that you only call `elapsedRealtime()` once per frame.