# Android OpenGL ES 2: Draw frame by frame

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am quite new to opengl es 2.0 on android. I am working on a project which draws a few plane indicators on screen(like altimeter, compass etc). After doing the tutorial from the official google dev site here http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html I just continued along this path, drawing circles, triangles, squares etc (only 2d stuff). I can make the drawn objects move using rotation and translation matrices, but the only way I know how to do this(except for how they did it in the tutorial) is like this in the onDrawFrame() method of my renderer class:

```
//set values for all Indicators
try {
Thread.sleep(1);
// for roll + pitch:
if(roll < 90) {
roll += 1.5f;
} else roll = 0;
if(pitch < 90) {
pitch += 0.5f;
} else pitch = 0;
// for compass:
if(compassDeg > 360) compassDeg = 0;
else compassDeg += 1;
//for altimeter
if(realAltitude >= 20000) realAltitude = 0;
else realAltitude += 12;
//for speedometer:
if(realSpeed >= 161) realSpeed = 0;
else realSpeed += 3;

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

roll, pitch, compassDeg, speed etc are the parameters the indicators receive and I designed them to move accordingly (if compassDeg = 0 for example, the compass will point north and so on). These parameters will eventually be received via bluetooth but for now I'm modifying them from the code directly because I don't have a bluetooth implementation yet. 
I am pretty sure this is not the best way to do it,  sometimes the drawn objects stutter and seem to go back a few frames, then back again and I don't think pausing the drawing method is a good idea in general.
I've seen that in the tutorial I mentioned in the beginning they use something like this:

```
//Use the following code to generate constant rotation.
//Leave this code out when using TouchEvents.        
long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() %4000L ;
float contAngle = -0.090f * ((int) time);
Matrix.setRotateM(contRotationMatrix, 0, contAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);
Matrix.multiplyMM(contMVPMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix4, 0, contRotationMatrix, 0);
```

which is still kinda weird I think, there has to be a more straightforward way in which to specify how to draw each frame, to rotate and translate objects frame by frame.
 So my question is how do I make everything move frame by frame or something like that, or at least how do I find out when one frame has been drawn?

Comment: Updating the transformations based on the time since the last frame, similar to what you have towards the end of your question, is the most common approach. This question/answer has some more details on how that can look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411287/android-timing-in-opengl-es-thread-is-not-monotonic/.

Comment: thanks I think I can manage with your answer

Comment: What I will typically do for non-monotonic clocks is define a min/max delta, typically something like 16ms to 200ms.

Then I will do some 'smoothing' over the values, usually the last 8 delta values averaged.